# How to Draw thousand of custom markers with custom info windows as it is hanging UI too much

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently i'm adding markers by using semaphore and sleeping thread but I need to show their info windows as well after some zoom level by changing markers with icon generator . But it is still stucking UI when markers are drawing . Can anybody help me and tell me how to draw thousands of markers and handle them without using cluster manager.

Answer (score 0):

add markers that inside the screen is enough to show, update markers on camera move,